# How to get specific data based on ID in MQTT broker using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mqtt

I managed to stream all runtime data in my MQTT broker however I want to display specific data based on their ID name using card widget in flutter.. How can I do that? This is my current code. Do I need to use write function?

```
MqttServerClient client = MqttServerClient(host, id);

Future<Stream<List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage>>>?> mqttSubscribe(
    {required String topic}) async {
  // init client
  client = MqttServerClient(host, id);
  client.port = port;
  client.autoReconnect = true;
  client.logging(on: true);
  client.keepAlivePeriod = 60;
  client.pongCallback = pong;
  client.onDisconnected = onDisconnected;

  final connMess = MqttConnectMessage()
      .authenticateAs(username, password)
      .withClientIdentifier(id)
      .startClean(); // Non persistent session for testing
  print('EXAMPLE::Mqtt client connecting....');
  client.connectionMessage = connMess;

  // Connect to mqtt broker
  try {
    await client.connect();
    // if connected, subscribe to a topic
    if (client.connectionStatus?.state == MqttConnectionState.connected) {
      // subscribe to topic
      client.subscribe(topic, MqttQos.atMostOnce);
      return client.updates;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } on NoConnectionException catch (e) {
    log(e.toString());
  }
}

void pong() {
  print('ping response arrived');
}

void onDisconnected() {
  print('disconnected');
}
```

Comment: Which ID? The only way to select MQTT messages is via their topic, messages do not include the client ID.

Comment: I have 3 sensorID in my MQTT broker. I can stream all data and display it in Flutter. However, only the last sensor information which is the third sensor that appeared on screen. The other two came out but only for a seconds then it will stop at sensor 3 information. It seems like the index I called hold 3 data in one time. How can I make all three sensors information to display on screen?

Comment: Without knowing the message payload format and seeing the code that actually handles the incoming messages we can't say